# Installing OSX Yosemite on completely empty drive

Tags: install, mac-mini, hdd

*Mac Mini c. mid-2011 500GB HDD*

The existing HDD is failing, have backed up and now looking to replace the drive. Don't want to spend $$$ for Apple service so going DIY. The hardware installation looks easy enough, and I can create a bootable USB key using a second Mac Mini at work, but...

All the sources suggest using the bootable USB key then pressing "Option" during bootup. Will this work on a Mac Mini with a new unformatted completely empty HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the option boot is independent of any OS present on the disk. You can always alt-boot, even booting off an external disk or network disk if there isn't any disk present in the computer at all.

Comment: Keep in mind, some versions of OSX don't support certain drives (NVMe SSD's) so you might have to use a bootable USB vs internet restore on older macs before (around) 2015.